# Strange vim behaviour

Tags: vim

I just installed vim on the windows machine, the executable file contained gvim and console vim. After running vim.exe I see this picture. [image]

The language is Russian but I don't know why only few symbols are displayed. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is your whole system set russian? (Including default code page for non unicode programs)

Comment: yeap, that's right

Comment: Other programs display russian correctly in the command window? Also: What kind of VIM is it? Cygwin? Directly compiled to Windows APIs?

Answer (score 4):

Did you choose a font for vim that contains all the Cyrillic characters and is mono-spaced? For example "Courier New (Cyrillic)"

There's some good advice at [nabble](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/enabling-cyrillic-character-display-support-td1162365.html)

> To see cyrillic characters in Console
>   Vim you need a terminal with Cyrillic  display, since Console Vim
>   can only use whatever characters the underlying  terminal offers.
>
> In gvim, you can display Cyrillic characters on two conditions: 
>   - 'encoding' must be set to some value which supports Cyrillic text.
>   This can  be an 8-bit encoding like koi8-r, cp1251 or ISO-8859-5, or a
>   multibyte  encoding like UTF-8. 
>   - Your 'guifont' must include Cyrillic glyphs. Lucida_Console has a
>   problem in  that its Cyrillic bold glyphs are slightly wider than its
>   unbold glyphs.  Courier_New is uglier but "saner".

(Update:)

In the [Vim download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) there are

> #### iconv library   libiconv
>
> A library used for converting character sets. Put "iconv.dll" in the same directory as gvim.exe to be able to edit files in many encodings. You can find the dll file in the bin directory of the "libiconv-win32" archive.
>
> #### newer intl library   libintl
>
> The included libintl.dll does not support encoding conversion. If you have installed the iconv library, as mentioned above, you can install a gettext library that uses it. Get "intl.dll" from the bin directory in the gettext-win32 archive and store it as "libintl.dll" in the same directory as gvim.exe, overwriting the file that may already be there.
>
> #### PC translations   vim##lang.zip    vim72lang.zip
>
> Only for 7.2 and earlier, for 7.3 these are included in the "rt" archive. Translated messages and menu files, packed for the PC. Use this to see non-English menus. The messages are only translated when the libintl.dll library is installed.

Comment: I tried both :set encoding=utf-8, setting encoding in _vimrc file, setting it to cp1251(which supports cyrillic), utf-8, utf-32, nothing changed. There are still strange characters instead of symbols.

Comment: yeah, I've read that post. gvim displays cyrillic symbols properly. The windows command line(cmd.exe) also support cyrillic characters, but the picture appears anyway.

Comment: Is this Vim 7.3 32-bit from http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc ?